# SyntaxError: unexpected token: keyword 'break'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un `switch` en **js**, y el único error que me da es ese, aquí el código:

```
switch (id) {
             case "0":
                 var user = <?php echo $vv0;?>
                 break;
             case "1":
                 var user = <?php echo $vv1;?>
                 break;
             case "2":
                 var user = <?php echo $vv2;?>
                 break;
             case "3":
                 var user = <?php echo $vv3;?>
                 break;
             case "4":
                 var user = <?php echo $vv4;?>
                 break;
             default:
                 var user = <?php echo $vv5;?>
         }
```

Si miro el error sucede en el primer *break*

Este *switch* está en el php, en un `.click`, chequeo si el valor de **id** está en un array y si es así ejecuto el `switch`

Comment: Hola @Aspoky , haz probado dejar el código php en string así? `var user = '<?php echo $vv0;?>';`

Comment: @SebastiánLagosYañez acabo de añadirlas y sale otro error direferente: `SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break`

Comment: Podrías especificar donde tienes ese código, en un archivo js o en el php ?

Comment: ya, pero eso especificarlo en la pregunta , edítalo  para que nos pongas en contexto a todos

Comment: @SebastiánLagosYañez ahora puse `default: break;` y ahora el unexpected es `'var'`, pero es un var que está fuera del switch, es decir el siguiente var del código

Comment: Porque no declaras el var user; antes del switch y una vez dentro solo le asignas valor ?

Comment: Estas asignando un string sin comillas

Comment: Como han dicho los compañeros, tienes que usar las comillas en la asignación. En el 2º comentario dices que las usaste y recibiste el mensaje *string literal contains an unescaped line break*  ... puede que en tu texto proveniente de PHP haya saltos de línea. Quizá convendría que revises cada valor en PHP y que sanees allí tus cadenas. O bien desde JS hagas algo así: `var user = "<?php echo $vv0;?>".replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, " ");` Pero los datos en PHP pueden tener también saltos de línea como `<br>` o  entidades HTML,  o comillas simples dentro... o... o... Lo mejor es **sanearlos en PHP**.

Comment: @A.Cedano No era eso, ya lo conseguí arreglar, pero gracias.

Comment: ¿Y cuál era el problema, para documentación de todos los que hemos tratado de ayudar?

Comment: @A.Cedano para explicarlo mejor, lo he subido en un .txt a mi servidor, (aquí el http://savepaste.ml/paste/GtoaCz5 , si quieren lo publico como respuesta y menciono a los que me ayudaron.

Comment: Realmente, viendo tu solución, animaría a cualquiera de los compañeros a publicar una respuesta y elegir esta como resuelta. Otras opciones son cerrar o eliminar la pregunta dado que el problema eran errores tipográficos.

Answer (score 1):

Realmente cuando encuentra error en `break`, no es ese el problema, sino la línea anterior (y en casi todos los casos, suele ser así).

Ya te han comentado varios de los errores:

- Falta de comillas (simples o dobles) para indicar la presencia de un String.
- Falta de dos puntos al final de la asignación a la variable (Lo que causa el error con el `break`).

Añadiría, por cuestiones estéticas y de eficiencia.

- Declarar la variable `user` una sola vez, fuera del switch con un valor dummy o sin valor. Seguramente trabajes con ella fuera del switch y no querrás tener problemas si es `undefined`.
- El `break` después del `default`. No es necesario en absoluto, pero no es mal hábito.

Y para continuar con el debug de errores, te recuerdo dos cosas:

- Los errores de **Javascript** solo son visibles en la consola de desarrollador del navegador que estés utilizando, o del IDE/Plataforma que uses para programar.
- Los errores de **PHP** son variados y dependen de la configuración
  del servidor, pero en general todos se **imprimen** en la página.

Te dejo un ejemplo rápido de cómo funcionaría tu función. Recuerda que cuando imprimes código PHP en la página, este no aparece, sino que se ejecuta. Sin embargo el código javascript suele ser visible al usuario y no aconsejo declarar demasiado código PHP ahí.

En el ejemplo reemplazo el primer `<` de la sentencia PHP con `/` para que puedas visualizarlo, pero recuerda que esto impide su ejecución.

```js
function cambiar(){
var user = '';
var id = document.getElementById('v1').value;
switch (id) {
             case "0":
                 user = "<?php echo $vv0;?>";
                 break;
             case "1":
                 user = "<?php echo $vv1;?>";
                 break;
             case "2":
                 user = "<?php echo $vv2;?>";
                 break;
             case "3":
                 user = "<?php echo $vv3;?>";
                 break;
             case "4":
                 user = "<?php echo $vv4;?>";
                 break;
             default:
                 user = "<?php echo $vv5;?>";
             break;
         }
// Borrar esto para que se imprima el tag PHP y se ejecute.
user = user.replace('<','/');
document.getElementById('frase').innerHTML = user;
}
```

```html
<p id='frase'> Aquí se pone el string de JS </p>
<input text="button" value="0" id="v1"/>
<input type="button" value="Botón" id="b1" onclick="cambiar();"/>
```

Comment: lo de la consola de javascript, ya la uso, y ya he implementado las soluciones que me dieron y me sirvieron para luego hallar la respuesta de mi parte. De todas maneras, gracias por tus recomendaciones.